# Facebook login buttons are not redendering in multilanguage

Tags: facebook, facebook-login, hebrew

We are using English and Hebrew language for our website. In English Facebook connect buttons are rendering properly but in Hebrew first time FLogin button coming in English not in Hebrew and all locale are set properly. Location of buttons are also not formatted properly in Hebrew site. Please help me about this.

Thanks!

To change the FB Buttons to required language I did these settings:

I am using XFBML, and load the JavaScript SDK in the appropriate locale for your site. For example, if our site is in Spanish, reference this script:
//connect.facebook.net/es_LA/all.js

For hebrew:
//connect.facebook.net/he_IL/all.js

All locales are provied here https://www.facebook.com/translations/FacebookLocales.xml
You can check your locale

I used in fb connect code the same way: but still FB API is providing us wrong results in some scenarios.
Following is the code I used:

```
<?php if ($facebookInvite) {  
   $lang = &JFactory::getLanguage();
   $currentLang =  $lang->get('tag'); // Now $currentlang has the locale of the   language selected
?>

// Now I pass $currentlang to "connect.facebook.net/locale_of_current_lang/all.js"    Please see below

<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/<?php echo $currentLang; ?>/all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
joms.jQuery(document).ready(function(){
function init(){
    FB.init({appId: '<?php echo $config->get('fbconnectkey');?>', status: false, cookie: true, xfbml: true});

}

if(window.FB) {
    init();
} else {
    window.fbAsyncInit = init;
}
```

});

```
</script>


<fb:login-button  onlogin="joms.connect.update();" scope="read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access,email,user_birthday,status_update,user_status"><?php echo JText::_('COM_COMMUNITY_SIGN_IN_WITH_FACEBOOK');?></fb:login-button>
```

Comment: We have the same problem, for some reason, if you are an APP outside Facebook the locales other then English don't work properly (And is always displayed in English). What I've noticed is that if I change my language inside Facebook (The whole Facebook site menus will be in Hebrew), then the login button will also written in hebrew properly. But I couldn't make it work by my own code.

Answer (score 0):

If the user is logged in Facebook, the login plugin will always display in the language of the user's (not site) configured locale. That's why it changes when you switch the user's locale to Hebrew.

If the user is **not** logged in, the login plugin will use the locale of the loaded js-sdk:

```
http://connect.facebook.net/LOCALE/all.js
```